# Recursive binary search in php

Tags: php, search, recursion

I have a function that gives me a number as result:

Now to make it simple I'll use an invented example:

```
   function generate($a) {return $a*2;}
   //this is just an example, the real generate function is really expensive in terms of speed and resources
```

I have also an array with the values to pass to that funcion:

```
$array = array(1,3,4,6,8,9,11);
```

I'd like to find the value of $array, that, passed to generate(), gives as output the number nearest to 5 and minor of it.

With a progressive search I would get this:

```
$array[0] => 2;
$array[1] => 6;
$array[2] => 8;
etc.
```

In this case I'd expect my search function to give as output the number 1 as this is value that, passed into generate(), gives 2 as output, the number nearest and minor to 5.

**Since the generate() function is really slow ( 1,5 sec on average ) I want to do a binary search with the hope of reducing the use of my function.**

So basically what I want to do is: slice $array into 2 pieces, use generate(), then slice againg etc.

I'm not an expert both in recursive function and binary search (it's my first script trying to do that).

However I tried to wrote some code I'm pasting below, however it doesn't work and honestrly I don't have a clear idea about it.

```
function generate($a) {return $a*2;}

$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

function find($array) {
    $first_half = array_slice($array,0,round(count($array)/2,0));
    $second_half = array_slice($array,round(count($array)/2,0));
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($first_half);
    print_r($second_half);
    echo "</pre>";
    $last = end($first_half);
    $last = generate($last);

    if($last > 4) {find($first_half);}
    else {}
}

find($array);
```

Can you help me?

Best regards,
Giorgio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this may be a good try for some academic research, in practice I think it's slower than a plain progressive approach.

What you would want is to optimize `generate()` (or the way it is called*) rather than the traversal algorithm.

---

*One such improvement is to replace this:

```
foreach($array as $k=>$v) $array[$k] = generate($v);
```

With this:

```
$array = array_map('generate', $array);
```

Answer (score 1):

For a binary search, here's what you want to do:

- If the list you're searching in has only one element, then return that element as the answer.
- Otherwise, find the element closest to the middle (if there are an even number of elements in the list, it won't be perfect, just round down).
- Calculate the value of `generate()` for that middle element:

  - If the result is 5 (or whatever value you're looking for), then return that middle element as the answer.
  - If the result is greater than five, recursively call `find()` with the list of all elements that came before the middle, and return that.
  - If the result is less than five, recursively call `find()` with the list of all elements that are after the middle, and return that.

Comment: But what should I do if there isn't any element that gives as result 5?
Like in my example.

Comment: Binary search will get you as close as it can to the element you're looking for. Since you're willing to accept answers that aren't perfect, you may have to modify your approach. Maybe add some logic to switch to a "progressive" approach once the list is small enough?